# Could not start the command

Tags: pdftex

everybody.

I know that this question has been asked a few times, but I just don't seem to resolve it. See if anybody can help me.

I've just finished reinstalling Texlive 2020. I have Linux Mint 20 Ulyana. I alse have added the directories to PATH, MANPATH, INFOPATH (although I honestly don't know what this means). I've runned

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux
```

and added

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPAT
```

to my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file as [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60765/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-manpath-or-infopath) suggests.

The error `Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Bandaprohibida".tex`  arises  when I try to "Quick Bluid" this test latex file

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\author{\textit{Samuel G. Guerrero Camarero}}

\title{\textbf{Práctica 10. Determinación de la banda prohibida del germanio.}}


\topmargin=-3cm
\oddsidemargin=-0.4cm
\textwidth=16.5cm
\textheight=25cm
\topmargin=-2cm

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace*{0.1cm}
\begin{center}\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.1mm} \end{center}
\bengin{abstract}
\normalsize ESTO E EL ABSTRACT DEL INFORME, CENTRADO Y LO PRIMERO DESPUES DE TITULO Y AUTOR.

\begin{center}\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.1mm} \end{center}
\vspace*{0.2cm}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

The 'funny' thing is that i have another tex (created like two weeks ago) in another location that compiles perfectly.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess you are running this from an editor? You started this editor from a menu or by double clicking a file?

In that case adding PATH to `bashrc` is not enough as bash is never used by the editor.

Add the PATH change to your `.profile` (there is also a global version), then log out and in again.

The profile data is executed as part of your login and all subsequent processes will inherit this data including the PATH change

(this is a **very** common error among linux users)

Comment: Yeap, that did it. I had to investigate a little bit because I hardly undestand what all these terms of ".profile", ".bash" and "PATH" mean, but I resolved it.
If anyone with this problem is like me, [this post](https://www.howtogeek.com/658904/how-to-add-a-directory-to-your-path-in-linux/) explains is pretty well.

Thank you, @daleif !